# Have max but rate is incorrect?

Tags: calculus

A car rental agency rents 220 cars per day at a rate of 31 dollars per day. For each 1 dollar increase in the daily rate, 5 fewer cars are rented. At what rate should the cars be rented to produce the maximum income, and what is the maximum income?

I got a rate of 6.5 dollars and a maximum income of 7031.25. The max income is right. My rate is incorrect. It's looking for dollars/day for the rate. Not sure how that is different.

Comment: This is *not* a related rates problem.

Comment: Anyway, if you show us your work, I'm sure we'll be able to point to the mistake, if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculations are correct. Maximizing the income

$$I=(31+x)(220-5x)=-5x^2+65x+6820$$

we get

$$I'=-10x+65$$

which shows that $I$ has a maximum in $x=6.5$ dollars/day. Thus, the rate at which the cars should be rented to produce the maximum income is $31+6.5=37.5$ dollars/day.

This corresponds to a total income of $$(31+6.5)(220-5\cdot 6.5)=7031.25$$ dollars/day.

Comment: So it looks like OP got 6.5 and interpreted it as the rate, instead of interpreting it as the increase in the rate. Probably because OP didn't start the work with a sentence like, "Let $x$ be the increase in the rate."

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a simple misinterpretation between rate and rate increase.